# IllegalAnnotationException: Two classes have the same XML type name

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, jbossws

I am developing web service under JBoss 5 and Java 1.6. What could possibly cause this exception? Below is my simplified web service code.

```
@Stateless
@WebService()
public class AccountWS {

@WebMethod()
public CreateAccountResponse createAccount(@WebParam(name = "request") CreateAccountRequest request) {
    return null;
}
```

And below is the full stack trace.

```
16:19:03,421 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/C:/Apps/jbdevstudio/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/sif_esb.esb/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfsfile:/C:/Apps/jbdevstudio/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/sif_esb.esb/
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1440)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1158)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1099)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:782)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:775)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build JAXB context
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.createJAXBContext(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:984)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.buildWebServiceMetaData(JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.java:151)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.setupProviderOrWebService(JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.java:50)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilderEJB3.buildMetaData(JAXWSMetaDataBuilderEJB3.java:76)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.start(UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.java:69)
at org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.java:129)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.ArchiveDeployerHook.deploy(ArchiveDeployerHook.java:76)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.AbstractWebServiceDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractWebServiceDeployer.java:60)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.WebServiceDeployerEJB.internalDeploy(WebServiceDeployerEJB.java:113)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Failed to create JAXBContext
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.createContext(CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.java:114)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.createJAXBContext(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:980)
... 39 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://kona.webservice.sif.unidata.com/}createAccountResponse". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at com.unidata.sif.kona.account.message.CreateAccountResponse
    at private com.unidata.sif.kona.account.message.CreateAccountResponse com.unidata.sif.webservice.kona.jaxws.CreateAccountResponse._return
    at com.unidata.sif.webservice.kona.jaxws.CreateAccountResponse
this problem is related to the following location:
    at com.unidata.sif.webservice.kona.jaxws.CreateAccountResponse

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:297)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:105)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.createContext(CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.java:108)
... 40 more
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem.

This problem occurs because JAX-WS generates a class for each method and the class name is constructed by concatenating `methodName` + `"Response"`. In my case, **the newly generated class by JAX-WS will have the same name as my response object**.

Example:

```
@Stateless
@WebService()
public class AccountWS {

    @WebMethod()
    public CreateAccountResponse createAccount(@WebParam(name = "request") CreateAccountRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

JAX-WS will generate a new class `CreateAccountResponse` for Web Method `createAccount` which has the same name as the response object.

Solution:

Make sure that **the name of the response object and method doesn't match**. The same thing applies to the method parameter as well.

Comment: +1 for sharing the right solution (and very useful info about JAX-WS)

Answer (score 15):

You have two XML schema elements with the same name (`createAccountResponse`) and the same namespace (`http://kona.webservice.sif.unidata.com/`) corresponding to the Java types `com.unidata.sif.kona.account.message.CreateAccountResponse` and `com.unidata.sif.webservice.kona.jaxws.CreateAccountResponse`. As the second one is "automagicaly" generated by the WebMethod annotation, it will be easier changing the XMLType anotation for the message element.

To solve it, you should change the `name` for one of them, or define two separated namespaces (one for the message elements, and another one for the WS request and response components). I recommend the last approach (two separated namespaces).

I.E:

**1.** Changing the name of the message element `com.unidata.sif.kona.account.message.CreateAccountResponse`.

```
@XMLType(name="CreateAccountResponseMsg", namespace="http://kona.webservice.sif.unidata.com")
```

**2.** Changing the namespace at message elements (package `com.unidata.sif.kona.account.message`)

```
@XMLType(name="CreateAccountResponse", namespace="http://kona.webservice.sif.unidata.com/message")
```

Comment: That is what the stack trace is trying to tell me I believe. But what I don't understand is why my other web services do not throw this exception.. I have checked against the other web services and the code is more or less similar.

Comment: With the information I have, I can't tell you the reason of this different behaviour. Sorry.

Comment: I found the cause.. checkout my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error but I couldn't ajust the classes with @XmlType annotation (coming from library)
So another solution is to provide a `com.unidata.sif.kona.account.message/package-info.java` with following code inside

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://kona.webservice.sif.unidata.com/")
package com.sopra.banking.processengine.servicecontract.v1_1.dto;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use `@WebMethod(operationName="differentFromMethodName")`. This will even change the interface method name on the client. JAX-WS still generates the classes for both wsgen and wsimport using the SEI's method name; but now the message element classes are different than the JAX_WS internally generated ones.

I did not want to touch the wsgen generated classes (message element classes).